# Multiple row Mysql insert statement with php if block

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that inserts multiple rows.THe form has six rows of fields.a user can decide to use all six rows or use a few.
When all six rows are filled i use the code below ,which works ok.

**The code below works fine**

```
    //Database connection string
 global $conn;

//insert Records
$strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values

('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product2."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price2."','".$Af_Qty2."','".$Af_Trans."'), 
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product3."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price3."','".$Af_Qty3."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product4."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price4."','".$Af_Qty4."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product5."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price5."','".$Af_Qty5."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product6."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price6."','".$Af_Qty6."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product1."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price1."','".$Af_Qty1."','".$Af_Trans."')";
db_exec($strSQLInsert,$conn);
```

However when i try to include a php if statement to leave out empty rows it give me an error.
in the code below i have tried testing the  first row but it is not working.if you have any ideas please assist.

```
//Database connection string
 global $conn;

//insert Records
$strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values

"if ($Af_Qty2 > 0){     //error occurs here
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product2."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price2."','".$Af_Qty2."','".$Af_Trans."'), 
  }"

('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product3."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price3."','".$Af_Qty3."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product4."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price4."','".$Af_Qty4."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product5."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price5."','".$Af_Qty5."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product6."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price6."','".$Af_Qty6."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product1."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price1."','".$Af_Qty1."','".$Af_Trans."')";
db_exec($strSQLInsert,$conn);
```

Comment: Oh man, ever heard of loops, arrays and `implode()`?

Comment: am still a beginner,still learning php, if you care to demonstrate i will be gratefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write If condition within double quotes. 
so try like below:

```
$strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values ";

if ($Af_Qty2 > 0){     //error occurs here
$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product2."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price2."','".$Af_Qty2."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
  }

$strSQLInsert .="('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product3."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price3."','".$Af_Qty3."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product4."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price4."','".$Af_Qty4."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product5."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price5."','".$Af_Qty5."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product6."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price6."','".$Af_Qty6."','".$Af_Trans."'),
('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product1."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price1."','".$Af_Qty1."','".$Af_Trans."')";
db_exec($strSQLInsert,$conn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
//Database connection string
global $conn;

//insert Records
$strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values ";

if ($Af_Qty2 > 0){   
    $strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product2."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price2."','".$Af_Qty2."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
}

$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product3."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price3."','".$Af_Qty3."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product4."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price4."','".$Af_Qty4."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product5."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price5."','".$Af_Qty5."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product6."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price6."','".$Af_Qty6."','".$Af_Trans."'),";
$strSQLInsert .= "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product1."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."','".$Af_Price1."','".$Af_Qty1."','".$Af_Trans."');";

db_exec($strSQLInsert,$conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in comment, you're just learning PHP, so I'd like to point out some things.

First of all, [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), just do your research, read what it is and how to prevent it.

Second of all, using `$Af_PriceN` cries for usage of [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```php
$prices = array(...);
$products = array(...);
```

Or in ideal world you would create [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) to contain all data:

```php
class Product {
    public $id;
    public $price;

    public function __construct($id, $price)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->price = $price;
    }
}

$p = array(
    new Product(1, 17.85),
    new Product(2, 19.47),
    ...
)
```

Then you could use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to build complex query:

```php
foreach( $p as $prod){
    // append product to query
}
```

But back to your example, assume you replaced each `$Af_fooN` by `$Af_foo = array`, then you could:

```php
$rows = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $Af_Product); $i++){
    if( $Af_Qty[$i]){
        continue;
    }

    $r = "('".$Af_Depot."','".$Af_Product[$i]."','".$Af_Date."','".$Af_Dist."',
          '".$Af_Price[$i]."','".$Af_Qty[$i]."','".$Af_Trans."')";

    array_push( $rows, $r);
}

// And join rows
if( count( $rows)){
    $strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values ";
    $strSQLInsert .= implode( ',', $rows);
}
```

Check out [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
But you're still not escaping values, so let's define `db_esc` as something similar to [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

```php
$r = "('".db_esc($Af_Depot)."','".db_esc($Af_Product[$i])...;
```

Which is really annoying to type, so you could use advantage of function like [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```php
// Inside loop:
$pieces = array( $Af_Depot, $Af_Product[$i], $Af_Date, $Af_Dist,
                 $Af_Price[$i], $Af_Qty[$i], $Af_Trans);

$pieces = array_map( 'db_esc', $pieces);

// And here comes a trick:
$r = "('" . implode( "','", $pieces) . ")";
```

So to sum up whole code:

```php
// Assuming
$Af_Depot = ...;
$Af_Date = ...;
$Af_Trans = ...;

$Af_Product = array();
$Af_Price = array();
$Af_Qty = array();

// Prepare
$rows = array();

// Go trough items:

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $Af_Product); $i++){
    if( $Af_Qty[$i]){
        continue;
    }

    $pieces = array( $Af_Depot, $Af_Product[$i], $Af_Date, $Af_Dist,
                     $Af_Price[$i], $Af_Qty[$i], $Af_Trans);

    $pieces = array_map( 'db_esc', $pieces);
    $r = "('" . implode( "','", $pieces) . ")";

    array_push( $rows, $r);
}

// And join rows
if( count( $rows)){
    $strSQLInsert = "insert into tbl_sales (Depot_Id,SalesProduct_Id,Sales_Date,Distributor_Id,Selling_Price,Units_Sold,Trns_type) values ";
    $strSQLInsert .= implode( ',', $rows);
}
```

Comment: wow.Am making the changes right away in order to use arrays and also correcting to prevent sql injection.Thank you so much.